# Deferred deep link to an Expo.io/ReactNative app.

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I’m handling deep links in my Expo.io ReactNative project using the [Linking library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/workflow/linking) and it works well, allowing me to open the app and pass in some routing data with a URL. But if the app isn’t installed on the device then it doesn’t work at all.

I know it’s possible for deferred deep links to persist data through an App Store install. What’s the best way to do this with ReactNative, or specifically with an Expo app?

Comment: Their documentation states that deferred deep links are supported via Branch.io

Comment: But the branch docs recommend ejecting expo https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native :/